# Azure Runbook error - "Test job is already running.. Error code: BadRequest."

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a run book with the powershell script

```
    $DataFactoryName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ADF-SandboxDataFactoryName'
    $ResourceGroupName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ADF-ResourceGroup_Sandbox'
    $pipelineName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ADF-PiplelineName'

  $parameters = @{  
     "pPL_param1" = "5"
  }  

  Connect-AzAccount -Identity
   Write-Output "$($DataFactoryName)"

   $DataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName - 
     ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName


  $Pipelines = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactory $DataFactory
  $Pipelines.Count | Select-Object @{label='PipelinesCount';expression ={$_}} | Format- 
   List

  Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName 
  $DataFactoryName -PipelineName $pipelineName -Parameter $parameters
  Write-Output "Done .... "
```

I was editing it back and forth, and it worked every step of the way,
But suddenly, I started getting the error

```
Test job is already running.. Error code: BadRequest.
```

I can't seem to fix it, please help.  I do not know where in Azure to stop running automation jobs ?  I don't even know when or how I started it, since I was only using the Test Pane for now.

Answer (score 1):

> Test job is already running....

***Error cause:*** The above error indicates that a job is already running but you are trying to run another job without finishing the first job.

Instead of checking output in `Test pane` click on `publish` and publish the runbook as shown.

[image]

Once it is published, it redirects to the below shown page. Simply click on `Start`, and the runbook job will begin executing the script automatically.

[image]

***Portal approach:***

After the job started, you will be able to see the following details and the job's `status`. To stop an active job, simply click the `Stop` button in the Portal.

[image]

Otherwise, you can also check the running jobs by going to below path:

`Automation Account -> Process Automation -> Jobs`

[image]

***PowerShell Approach:***

You can also stop the automation job using Azure PowerShell with the `Stop-AzAutomationJob`  command. Pass the job ID along with the automation account name and resource group name in which the automation account exists.

```
Stop-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -Id dad589c0-3877-4b9f-955e-16bcef412fb5  -ResourceGroupName "Jahnavi"
```

[image]